# How to use asset URLs in style binding with Vite

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I want to show a background image from my assets folder. When I use an image tag, the image is shown properly, so the image is well placed, but throws a 404 when I use the `background-image` style. Any idea about what is happening?. I am using Vue 3 with TypeScript and Vite 2.

This does not resolve the URL:

```html
<div style="background-image: url(./assets/img/header.png)"
></div>
```

But this does:

```html
<img src="./assets/img/header.png" alt="Header" />
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The URL needs to be resolved with `import` in `<script>`. `@vue/compiler-sfc` does not automatically resolve the URLs in `<div>.style`, but it does for `<img>.src`, which is why your second example works correctly.

### Solution

Use the `import` keyword in a `<script>` block to expose the resolved image URL to the template:

```html
<script setup>
import imagePath from '@/assets/logo.svg'
</script>

<template>
  <div class="logo" :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${imagePath})` }"></div>
</template>

<style>
.logo {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-binding-asset-url-in-style?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: What if I want to use backgroundImage on a pseudo-element? This wouldn't work with inline css, would it?

Comment: Well, that's annoying, Vite. Who thought that one up?

Comment: I have the same issue with a background image showing up on the entire site. How would this trick work for that?

Comment: If anyone is inside react functional component like me then  ```:style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${imagePath})` }"``` wont work, ```style={{'backgroundImage': `url(${imagePath})`}}``` would

Answer (score 8):

This is due to vite can't handle alias by default, so we need to set up an alias in vite config file.

there is no need to setup the import image in script tag.

just put the below code in vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "/src"),
      "~@": path.resolve(__dirname, "/src"),
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The OP is not using an alias in the URL. Also, setting up the alias would not automatically resolve the path in the style binding for the `<div>` ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-style-binding-unresolved?file=src/App.vue)).