# Vite can't resolve paths from CSS url()

Tags: javascript, css, vite

I have a Vite 4 project that uses vanilla JS & no frameworks. When I reference an asset using CSS `url()`, it throws a 404 error. The path works fine in HTML `img` src. I saw [the answer for Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67744676/16407971) but don't know how it applies to my project without a framework. Merely importing an asset from the `index.js` file changes nothing.

_search-input.scss

```css
.search-input {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("../../assets/icons/search.svg");
}
```

Index.js:

```js
import "./styles/index.scss"

console.log("index file")
```

Project structure:

```
├── src/
│   ├── assets/
│   │   └── icons/
│   │       └── search.svg
│   ├── styles/
│   │   ├── components/
│   │   │   └── _search-input.scss
│   │   └── index.scss
│   └── index.js
└── index.html
```

I removed a single `../` from the path and now the image loads. However, isn't `../assets/icons/search.svg` an invalid path? From `search-input.scss` I'm supposed to go up two levels to get to `src/` and then reach `assets`. My IDE also complains that this path can't be resolved. Why does this work? What is this path relative to?

Comment: Do you know the URL of the image? (The actual, deployed to dev/staging/production/whatever you are testing with, URL?). When the browser resolves teh relative URL you are using, does it match it? What does the Network tab of the browser's developer tools show for the request for that image?

Comment: The URL for requested image is `http://localhost:5173/assets/icons/search.svg`. When I removed a single `../`, the image loaded with the URL `http://localhost:5173/src/assets/icons/search.svg`. I edited my post, not sure why it works.

Comment: I just noticed that `_search-input.scss` is a partial loaded from `index.scss` file. Could this be issue related to how SASS loads partials and resolves path?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand what the problem is without the source code. I had a problem when building projects. I created subdirectories in the dist folder through vite.config for styles, pictures. Used build.rollupOptions.output.assetFileNames. For this reason, paths to images and fonts were not correctly created in css. This is due to the settings of the vite itself.

I searched for a long time how to fix this and found an experimental parameter that helped me solve the problem.

[Advanced Base Options](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#advanced-base-options)

Here is my piece of code that helped me.

With this function, I find the file in which I need to edit the paths and change them. The interface of the function is well described. It is not clear what exactly needs to be returned, but in theory it should be the path to the file.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '',
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    open: true,
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        chunkFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
        entryFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
        assetFileNames: function ({ name }) {
          if (/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/.test(name ?? '')) {
            return 'assets/img/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          }

          if (/\.css$/.test(name ?? '')) {
            return 'assets/css/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          }

          if (/.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)/.test(name ?? '')) {
            return 'assets/fonts/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          }
          // default value
          // ref: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputassetfilenames
          return 'assets/[name]-[hash][extname]';
        },
      },
    },
  },
  // Функция которая поможет решить проблему путей
  experimental: {
    renderBuiltUrl: function (filename: string, { hostId, hostType, type }: { hostId: string, hostType: 'js' | 'css' | 'html', type: 'public' | 'asset' }) {
      if (type === 'asset') {
        if (hostType === 'css') {
          const stringRemove = 'assets';
          const stringLength = stringRemove.length;
          const stringPesence = filename.indexOf(stringRemove);
          if (-1 !== stringPesence) {
            console.log('..' + filename.substring(stringLength));
            return '..' + filename.substring(stringLength);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand it, all paths to image files must be specified relative to the root sass file in which other sass files are compiled.

./assets/icons/icon.svg in your case

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```html
.app-bg {
  background: url("@/assets/background1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS url() paths are relative to the current css location, in contrast to HTML img src which is not relative to the current path.

Maybe try to add another `../` to your css path.